# Converting map extent from 3857 projection to 26331 projection

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to convert extent which is in 3857 projection into 26331 projection in OpenLayers by `ol.proj.transformExtent(map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()),'EPSG:3857','EPSG:26331')`

Comment: Have you tried to use `EPSG:26331` instead of `26331` in your code?

Comment: I used EPSG:26331

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Did you define `EPSG:26331` with proj4? (example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image-custom-proj.html).